# Expression must be modifiable lvalue - c++ Error

Tags: c++, malloc

I got the error when I execute the following code.

```
int *p;
p = (int *)malloc(128*sizeof(int *));
for (int i = 0; i < 128; i++)
{
    (*p + i) = 0;
}


Expression must be modifiable lvalue
```

Comment: `*` has a higher precedence than `+`.

Comment: What is the solution for that?

Comment: Parentheses, of course. Always the solution when the precedence rules don't work the way you want.

Comment: If you want a buffer all set to 0, use calloc or memset instead of doing this. They are faster.

Comment: @LtWorf If they are, then you have a very poor compiler.

Comment: If you don't enable optimizations, they are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lvalue is incorrect.
Try
     *(p+i)=0;

I think that should work.

Comment: Even better would be `p[i] = 0;`

Answer (score 3):

The issue is that `(*p + i) = 0` is parsed as `((*p) + i) = 0` (i.e. dereference `p`, add `i` to it, and then try to assign to the result of that).

To fix, rewrite

```
(*p + i) = 0;
```

as

```
*(p + i) = 0;
```

or

```
p[i] = 0;
```

(I think the latter is more readable.)

Better yet, seeing that this is C++ and not C, use `std::vector<int>` and remove the need to explicitly manage memory.